# What is the cleanest way to trim the drywall around this electrical box?

Tags: drywall

I'm mounting a ceiling fan into an existing ceiling fan electrical box.

The drywall was finished around the box such that it's too close to the box and will be in the way of the hanging bracket and fan trim. I'll need to cut it back. What's the best way to trim back drywall in a situation like this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't get it. It looks like your ceiling is at an angle. Won't the fan blades hit the ceiling?

Comment: Instead of cutting the drywall why not add on to the area where the fan trim will sit, that's assuming you can move the electrical box or get a deeper one.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose Good idea. I am not sure I want to replace the box, but perhaps I can cut a plate that can go between the box and the fan.

Comment: Extending the mounting plate down as suggested might be the simplest fix. Just keep in mind that you need to extend the box down as well (look for a "Ceiling Box Extender" of the right size). If you don't extend the box the enclosure does not meet fire code (also your house could burn down when a wire nut works loose).

Comment: @Harper, the fan hangs lower in the room from a down rod like this fan: http://www.eaglerc.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/vaulted-ceiling-fan-farmhouse-ceiling-fan-bedroom-rustic-with-exposed-beams-exposed-beams-vaulted-ceiling-angled-ceiling-fan-mount.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up following suggestions from @PlatinumGoose and @Stanwood by extending the electrical box lower using a 2x8 cut to fit, as well as a [electrical box extender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007IZKDUC).

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: Just make sure the fan mounting screws go into the 2x8 and not the extension

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Yes, a good things to note. The fan bracket is secured with 6” lag screws that go through my block and up into whatever is above the original ceiling fan box.