# How do I finish this wood box extension I made, to match the drywall around it?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

The previous owners put a ceiling fan box in such a place that the ceiling fan bracket and the [drywall would have conflicted](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/140146/what-is-the-cleanest-way-to-trim-the-drywall-around-this-electrical-box). I extended the electrical box lower, using a piece of 2"x8" that was cut to fit and a [ceiling electrical box extender](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007IZKDUC).

It's ready to finish/paint before I hang the fan.

What's the best way to make the wood match the surrounding drywall? Should I just prime and paint? Should I drywall tape the seams and mud with joint compound, then sand, prime, and paint?

I would like it to look nice, but also it is 10' off the ground so close up perfection is not important.

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]

Comment: I vote for prime and paint the wood without any taping or sealing of the joint..  This is a unique mounting and it's best for the construction to be apparent so one can evaluate the security of the mounting.  Much later on even you yourself might not remember exactly how you did it.

Comment: Is the box extender fan rated?  Are you using a hugger style fan at this location?  Or a down rod model?  I can’t see how you can possibly solidly mount a ceiling fan with this arrangement.

Comment: @Tyson It’s a down rod fan. The fan bracket is mounted using 6” lug screws that go through my extension block and into the existing fan box. Structurally nothing has changed. The extender electrical box is a sleeve that only prevents the wires from touching the wood while they go through the block I added. It supports no weight.

Comment: Why wouldn’t a longer down rod have worked? As it is I’d overlay with drywall tape mud sand prime paint

Answer (score 1):

I have used a wall paper that has the same surface texture as drywall in the past to cover custom jobs like this. I like the look better than just primer and painting. From my experiance there will be less cracks at the interface from the block of wood to the ceiling and the paint color is uniform where going from sheetrock to wood there is usually a shift because of the texture difference.